# What version of Ubuntu to run on old MacBook Pro?

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, gpu

I've been trying to run Ubuntu 20.04 in dual-boot on an old MBP mid-2010 intel dual-core 13', but it's unstable. My hunch is that it has something to do with the graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce 320M). Would I be better off using an older version like 18.04 or 16.04?

Grateful for any advice - thanks!